# Why is this build association for has_many belongs_to not working in Rails 3.2.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 models setup as follows:

```
class StripePlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location, :name, :price, :plan_type
  has_many :stripe_subscriptions, :foreign_key=>:plan_id
end

class StripeSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :plan_id, :stripe_customer_token, :teacher_id
  belongs_to :stripe_plan
  belongs_to :teacher
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :stripe_subscription, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I do something like the following at the rails console:

```
 @stripe_plan = StripePlan.find(params[:plan_id])
 @stripe_subscription = @stripe_plan.stripe_subscriptions.build(:teacher_id=>params[:teacher_id],:plan_id=>params[:plan_id],:email=>params[:email])
```

where params={:teacher_id=>1, :plan_id=>1, :email="example@example.com"}.  Here you can assume a plan with id of 1 exists, as well as the teacher.

**Now, @stripe_subscription.stripe_plan.nil? evaluates to true.**  But it shouldn't.  Because if I had a model called "Subscription" and a model called "Plan" with the same setup, then @subscription.plan.nil? evaluates to false.  This is puzzling and I've spent a couple of hours to try and figure it out.  Have I found a bug or what am I doing wrong?  Maybe part of the issue is the :foreign_key is :plan_id instead of :stripe_plan_id?  I was getting another bug until I set the :foreign_key attribute in has_many.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a `@stripe_plan.save` to save the item to DB. its still in memory. If you did a `@stripe_plan.stripe_subscriptions` you will still see it because its saved to the object `@stripe_plan`. until you save `@string_plan` it won't be in the DB.

You could also do
`@stripe_subscription = @stripe_plan.stripe_subscriptions.create(:teacher_id=>params[:teacher_id],:plan_id=>params[:plan_id],:email=>params[:email])`

which will create the item and save to the DB

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `:plan_id=>params[:plan_id]` in `build`, since that would make use of `stripe_plan`'s `id`.

The other thing  you should do is look at the cosole. You might have missed out some attributes that you have not white-listed.

Check out [Rails 3 -- Build not saving to database (Railscast 196)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235346/rails-3-build-not-saving-to-database-railscast-196), it seems like you've hit into a similiar issue.

Comment: thanks you're right about not using :plan_id in build; On my console a StripeSubscription is created from the build.  There's no mass-assignment error.  it's just that I can't seem to traverse @stripe_subscription.stripe_plan via the association...I have the same has_many/belongs_to setup with 2 other models that works, the only thing different seems to be the model names...that's why this is puzzling and driving me slightly crazy :)